# Confusion regarding Function/operator overloading

Tags: c++

Consider the following self contained program.

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename Ty>
struct Foo
{
    Foo& operator=(Foo foo){ return foo; }    
private:
    Foo& operator=(Foo& foo){ return foo; }
};
template<typename Ty>
struct Bar
{
    template<typename U>
    Bar& operator=(Bar<U> bar){ return bar; }
private:
    Bar& operator=(Bar& bar){ return bar; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> f1, f2;
    f1 = f2;            // (1)
    Bar<int> b1, b2;
    b1 = b2;            // (2)
    f1 = Foo<int>(f2);  // (3)
    b1 = Bar<int>(b2);  // (4)
}
```

Both `Foo` and `Bar` overloads the assignment operator, and in using both of them, fails to compile, unless, we explicitly cast it to the type of the object. Also, though, the assignment from both `Foo` and `Bar` fails, yet the failures are different. Note, I do understand why the call is ambiguous when a function is overloaded based on reference and value. But what I fail to understand is

1. Why using explicit template argument changes the compiler failure. Statement (1) and (2) gives different error, where (1) claims the call is ambiguous, where as (2) claims it cannot access private data members. For ex. when compiling with VC++ (similar behavior with g++), I see the following errors

   ```
   1>Source.cpp(8): warning C4522: 'Foo<int>' : multiple assignment operators specified
   1>          Source.cpp(20) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Foo<int>' being compiled
   1>Source.cpp(21): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
   1>          Source.cpp(7): could be 'Foo<int> &Foo<int>::operator =(Foo<int> &)'
   1>          Source.cpp(5): or       'Foo<int> &Foo<int>::operator =(Foo<int>)'
   1>          while trying to match the argument list '(Foo<int>, Foo<int>)'
   1>Source.cpp(23): error C2248: 'Bar<int>::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Bar<int>'
   1>          Source.cpp(15) : see declaration of 'Bar<int>::operator ='
   ```
2. Why both (3) and (4) where I perform an explicit cast doesn't fail. Why it isn't ambiguous nor its trying to access the reference overload which is private.
3. Why in case (2) it gives preference to the reference overload in contrast to the value overloaded function/operator.

**Note** An [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/sbLLko) version in case you want to play with the code.
**Note** Can you please provide appropriate references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Both overloads of `Foo::operator=` are equally good matches for overload resolution purposes - hence ambiguity. That's not the case for `Bar::operator=` - other things equal, overload resolution prefers non-templates over templates. So the private `operator=` is a better match - but of course it then fails access check.
2. `Foo<int>(f2)` is a temporary, and can't bind to non-const reference. The overload taking its parameter by value is the only viable candidate.
3. It doesn't give preference to reference overload - it gives preference to non-template overload. You can confirm that by switching them around.

Comment: Aha .. I understand your second point, my bad, I completely overlooked. But then I am still wondering why using explicit template arguments changes the behavior. Also, can you please provide a reference to support your third point?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `using explicit template arguments`. Which two lines do you compare the behavior of?

Comment: Red herring. Lines 3 and 4 are casts, casts produce temporaries, temporaries do not bind to non-const references.

Comment: `Foo& operator=(Foo foo){ return foo; }` vs `template<typename U>
    Bar& operator=(Bar<U> bar){ return bar; }`. The former states, the call is ambiguous where as the second state, it cannot access private member.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, I got that from IgorTandetnik 's answer. It was my bad that I overlooked. But then there are few more confusions I need to clarify.

Comment: **13.3.3/1** a viable function `F1` is defined to be a *better* function than another viable function `F2` if ... `F1` is a non-template function and `F2` is a function template specialization...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thank you. Your last comment concludes the answer. You may wan't to update this in to your answer.